# Models of ZF with a Russell Socks Set

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Define a *Russell socks set* as a countable set of (pairwise disjoint) pairs such that no infinite subset has a choice function. Of course, if ZFC is consistent then it proves that no such set exists (as the axiom of choice is precisely the statement that every set has a choice function). On the other hand, it is known to be consistent with ZF that such a set exists.

Many wonderful and entertaining consequences of such a set existing in a model of ZF can be found in papers such as '*On the number of Russell's socks [...]*' by Herrlich and Tachtsis or in Ethan Thomas' undergraduate thesis on the subject.

Neither of these papers explicitly construct a model of ZF containing a Russell socks set. Are any of the more common models such as Cohen's known to contain such a set? Is it easy to construct a model containing one?

Any reference would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ethan Thomas's [thesis](https://math.dartmouth.edu/theses/undergrad/2014/Thomas-thesis.pdf).

Comment: In his thesis he constructs models containing so called psuedo-Russel socks sets. These are models containing an infinite set of pairs such that any subset contained in a given non-principal ultrafilter has no choice function. This is slightly weaker than the definition of a Russel socks set above I believe.

Comment: (The paper by Brunner mentioned in the references of the Herrlich-Tachtsis paper exhibits a model with Russell cardinals where every infinite set admits a Hausdorff topology with infinitely many nonisolated points, and the power set of the reals is well-orderable. The paper is available [here](http://www.dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107184/ArchMath_020-1984-1_5.pdf).)

Comment: Take a look at [MR3411399](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3411399). Eleftherios Tachtsis. *[On the existence of free ultrafilters on $\omega$ and on Russell-sets in $\mathsf{ZF}$](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/bulletin-polish-acad-sci-math/all/63/1/91097/on-the-existence-of-free-ultrafilters-on-omega-and-on-russell-sets-in-zf)*, Bull. Pol. Acad. Sci. Math. **63** (2015), no. 1, 1–10. In that paper, Tachtsis shows that in Blass's model where every ultrafilter is principal there are Russell sets.

Comment: [MR0476510](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=476510). Andreas Blass. *A model without ultrafilters*, Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. **25** (1977), no. 4, 329–331.

Comment: @Andrés: One has to wonder, how ubiquitous are Russell sets in previously known models of set theory. And even "generalized Russell sets" with replacing countable by $\kappa$ and infinite subfamily by $<\kappa$ families.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was thinking that. They are probably rather common.

Comment: Thank you to you both for your references and answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Cohen's *second* model of $\lnot\sf AC$ is a model in which there is a Russell set.

The proof can be found in Jech, "The Axiom of Choice" in Chapter 5, section 4. While Jech does not include the statement that the resulting set is a Russell set, it is implicit in the proof of Lemma 5.19.

Additionally, Fraenkel's second model of $\sf ZFA$ has a Russell set, and in the same book by Jech, he provides "transfer theorems" for transferring some results from models with atoms to models of $\sf ZF$ (without atoms). These include the existence of a Russell set as well. Other transfer theorems (Pincus, Hall) are equally suitable for the job also.